# How to scrape this website .asp - using R?

Tags: r

I am triying to download the table of the next webpage:

http://fantasynba.movistarplus.es/basketball/reports/player_rankings.asp

with the next code

```
rm(list = ls())
library(rvest)
nba <- html("http://fantasynba.movistarplus.es/basketball/reports/player_rankings.asp")

data_nba<-nba %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>%
  html_text()


df_aux<-matrix(nrow = length(data_nba)/15,ncol=15)
df_aux<-as.data.frame(df_aux)
i<-1
for(i in 1:length(data_nba)/15){
  df_aux[i,]<-data_nba[(15*i-14):(15*i)]
  df_aux[i,1]<-gsub("\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t","",df_aux[i,1])
  df_aux[i,1]<-gsub("\t","",df_aux[i,1])
}
data_nba<-df_aux


names_nba<-nba %>%
  html_nodes("thead") %>%
  html_text()
names_nba<-gsub(c("\r"),"",names_nba)
names_nba<-gsub(c("\n"),"",names_nba)
names_nba<-gsub(c("\t"),"",names_nba)
names_nba<-strsplit(names_nba," ")
names_nba<-names_nba[[1]]
names_nba<-names_nba[which(names_nba!="")]

names(data_nba)<-names_nba
```

The problem is that the code only download the players with the position (see "Posición" in Spanish) Base. the other positions ("Alero", "Pivot"), I could not download them.

I have tried everything within my reach and I have not been able to.

Can you help me to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sth. like the following helps?

```
result <- list()

url_base <- "http://fantasynba.movistarplus.es/basketball/reports/player_rankings.asp"

for (i in 1:3) {

   nba_session <- html_session("http://fantasynba.movistarplus.es/basketball/reports/player_rankings.asp")

   form <- html_form(nba_session)[[1]]

   fillform <- set_values(form, "pos" = i) 
   position_nba <- submit_form(session = nba_session, form = fillform) 

   # returns full table

   data_nba <- nba_session %>%
      html_nodes("#searchResults") %>%
      html_table() %>%
      .[[1]]

   result[[i]] <- data_nba
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it continues with the problem.

Try this:

unique(result[[1]]==result[[3]])

and

unique(result[[2]]==result[[3]])

It will return you 

TRUE TRUE...

So, you are downloading the same table, three times.

Comment: looks like the "Submit" button is not clicked while the other dropdowns are filled. I'll see if I can fix this

Comment: Apparently the submit button has no "name" attribute that allows me to call it. i'm afraid I cannot provide a better solution without PhantomJS (or maybe RSelenium which I haven't tried yet due to non-admin rights on my machine).